# Jersey 1.9 webapp on Tomcat 8 (Eclipse) upgrade to 1.19.1 cause 404 error

Tags: eclipse, maven, servlets, jersey, tomcat8

if I change the jersey version to a higher one than 1.9 then a 404 error returns when I try to run the servlet. 
Here are some details of my setting:
- Tomcat 8
- Eclipse Luna
- Maven for integrating the lib

I guess there are maybe changes in the syntax of the RestFul service provide since 1.9, but I'm not sure. So here is the servlet code:

```
import javax.ws.rs.DefaultValue;
import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.PathParam;
import javax.ws.rs.QueryParam;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;

@Path("/helloWorldREST")
public class HelloWorldREST {

    @GET
    @Path("/{parameter}")
    public Response responseMsg( @PathParam("parameter") String parameter,
            @DefaultValue("Nothing to say") @QueryParam("value") String value) {

        String output = "Hello from: " + parameter + " : " + value;

        return Response.status(200).entity(output).build();

    }

}
```

Comment: I have downloaded the libs as archive and added manually, which works now with the newest version of 1. 
Seems like maven has some trouble to find the lib, but I get no message about this. How can I check which libs are really downloaded by maven?

Comment: With Jersey 1.19, you need `jersey-servlet` also

Comment: Thanks. But one question. Why I don't get any message about this (e.g. error)?